# How to replace Quarkus Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus 1.1.1.Final and I've enabled `smallrye-openapi`.

As a default, Quarkus OpenAPI bundles Swagger UI, but OpenAPI official generator is using RapiDoc. (RapiDoc - Web Component based Swagger & OpenAPI Spec Viewer https://mrin9.github.io/RapiDoc/ )

In this context, our team prefer RapiDoc to Swagger UI.
We want to replace bundled Swagger UI with RapiDoc, but there are no configuration properties on the Quarkus document. (Quarkus - Using OpenAPI and Swagger UI https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui )

Is there any workaround on this?